# Is there any difference between Discourse Analysis and critical discourse analysis?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics, discourse-analysis

I would like to know if **Discourse Analysis** and **Critical Discourse Analysis** are two distinctive theories or are the same.

If distinctive, what is the main point that distinguishes them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discourse analysis isn't a theory (it makes no claims), it is an area of investigation. "Critical Discourse Analysis" is a specific theory of discourse analysis. I am not sure if "Critical Discourse Analysis" actually makes a claim, but at least it is superficially "a theory".

Comment: To add, at least from what I've heard, the 'critical' in CDA is 'critical' as in lowercase critical theory, i.e. in aim of unmasking hidden power structures and ideologies.